# iOS set `isHidden` after updating `alpha`

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, alpha

is there any reason to set `isHidden` to false, after updating the alpha value of a view? E.g.

```
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 1.0,
    animations: {
        self.alpha = 0.0
    },
    completion: { isFinished in
        if isFinished {
            self.isHidden = true
        }
    }
)
```

It seems like a common pattern, but I could not find any documentation why?

Comment: Performance reasons. Also a hidden view does not receive any input events. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622585-ishidden and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387491/are-uiviews-with-alpha-0-or-hidden-yes-still-a-performance-expense.

Answer (score 0):

It is related with performance issues, one might think that since we are setting it's alpha to 0.0 to make it visible it might still be interactable. As Rob mentioned in the comments, once the alpha value is lower than 0.1 it wont be possible to interact with that view object anyways.

It affects the performance of your application as Andre mentioned in the comments. Your view still be existing in your `ViewController`, and keep using some resources to exist on the screen.

Comment: [Hit-testing (for touch delivery) ignores any view whose alpha is less than 0.01.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest?language=objc) So the first paragraph of your answer is incorrect. However, the second part is true: other parts of UIKit (or Core Animation) might perform better if the view is hidden.

Comment: Wow didnt know that, I will update my answer. Thanks! @robmayoff